# Why are methods so slow?

Tags: python, function

Ok, I understand in languages like C++ why calling virtual method defined in a class is slower than calling a non-virtual method (you have to go through the dynamic dispatch table to lookup the correct implementation to call).

But in Python, if I have:

```
list_of_sets = generate_a_list_containg_a_bunch_of_sets()
intersection_of_all = reduce(list_of_sets[0].intersection, list_of_sets)
```

This is **dramatically** (in my experiments about 40%) slower than:

```
list_of_sets = generate_a_list_containg_a_bunch_of_sets()
intersection_of_all = reduce(set.intersection, list_of_sets)
```

What I don't get is why that should be so much slower, the method lookup (I would think) would happen on the call to reduce, so the inside of reduce where the intersection method is actually called shouldn't have to be looked up again (it just just reuse the same method reference).

Could someone illuminate where my understanding is flawed?

Comment: Do you see this difference for many small sets, or for a few large ones? I'd expect binding issues to matter in the first case, but not in the latter (when the actual intersection work dominates the overheads). I see two conflicting answers (one of them twice), and can't tell which is correct.

Comment: It was for both a small (a list of about 10 sets) and medium (a list of about 100 sets that were randomly generated).  The reason was explained by Sven in his answer below.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is completely unrelated to method binding etc.  The first version computes the intersection of three sets in each iteration, while the second version only intersects two sets.  This is easy to see if we use the explicit loops instead.

Variant 1:

```
intersection = list_of_sets[0]
for s in list_of_sets[1:]:
    intersection = list_of_sets[0].intersection(intersection, s)
```

Variant 2:

```
intersection = list_of_sets[0]
for s in list_of_sets[1:]:
    intersection = set.intersection(intersection, s)
```

(Would you agree now Guido has a point?)

Note that this will probably be even faster:

```
intersection = list_of_sets[0]
for s in list_of_sets[1:]:
    intersection.intersection_update(s)
```

Comment: And yup, looping with intersection_udpate was a smidge faster (about 3%) than the reduce with set.intersection.

Comment: @AdamParkin: Since I would have expected a much bigger difference for non-trivial cases, so [I did some timings myself](https://gist.github.com/1934353).  And indeed I found the loop version to be more than twice as fast as the `reduce()` version.  Not having to create a new set in every iteration *should* make a difference!

Comment: It would appear that this is the result of my test set being simply too small (it was only about 100 sets, each of which had ~30 items).

Comment: @AdamParkin: Probably the intersection became empty pretty soon.  I made sure all sets had a substantial number of elements in common.

Comment: Yeah, I made sure the sets had elements in common, but only ~10 or so, so after the first couple intersections it had pretty much converged on what the final solution was.